# List all possible combinations from a complex dictionary of lists of lists?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a dictionary which contains strings, `None`, lists, and lists of lists as shown in the example below.

The desired result is a list of dictionaries. The number of dictionaries equal to the number of total permutations possible.

The requirements are that each of the dictionaries may have `None` or a list of values with the exception that `varVal` has a list of lists of length equal to the length of `varName` (i.e., `len(d['varVal'] = len(d['varName']`).

I think the `None` issue is already taken care of and keeping the `varString` as a list prevents breaking the string into characters.

I've scoured many an overflow post with [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171173/list-all-possible-permutations-from-a-python-dictionary-of-lists) the most helpful so far though I've ran out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Example**

This example does **not** generate the desire result :(

```
import itertools as it

d={}
d['varString']=['ExampleText']
d['n1']=[1,100]
d['n2']=None
d['varName']=['varA','varB']
d['varVal']=[[10],[1,0]]

df = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if v is not None}
keys, values = zip(*df.items())
res = [dict(zip(keys, v)) for v in it.product(*values)]
```

**Desired Result**

Extra space added between dictionaries to help the visual presentation.

```
res = [
    {'n1': 1,
     'varName': ['varA', 'varB'],
     'varString': 'ExampleText',
     'varVal': [[10], [0]]},

    {'n1': 100,
     'varName': ['varA', 'varB'],
     'varString': 'ExampleText',
     'varVal': [[10], [0]]},

    {'n1': 1,
     'varName': ['varA', 'varB'],
     'varString': 'ExampleText',
     'varVal': [[10], [1]]},

    {'n1': 100,
     'varName': ['varA', 'varB'],
     'varString': 'ExampleText',
     'varVal': [[10], [1]]}
]
```

Comment: Is it feasible to normalize your input first? ATM you have entries you want to build permutations from and also entries which should be kept as they are. Can you promote all variables to be keys of your dictionary? (I'm talking about `varA` and `varB` here)

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What does the input represent? What does the output represent? What you are trying to do? It looks like you are trying to compute all possible assignment of some "variables". I bet the issue is simply that you have chosen the wrong way to represent your data, and a smarter representation would yield what you actually want much more easily.

Comment: @PeterE, I see where your going. There is a possibility that I could do that as there are standard names expected in the dictionary. I could then grab all off-standard names and group them in a subsequent step. I'll try that work around. Not ideal but workable.

Comment: From the input and your desired result, it doesn't appear that all values that consisted of a list of elements were treated in the same manner—some were split up and some not. What determines which way such values are handled?

Comment: @martineau, the `varName` and `varVal` are the exception. `varVal` represents a list of values associated with a `varName`. For example `varA = [10]` and `varB = [1,0]`. This association is the issue which causes `it.product` not to work in the way I have coded in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PeterE's comment got me to think about the problem a little different which led to this answer.

This answer handles the entries that are causing the issues separately and then does some post-processing to get return the required format. Essentially creating and additional step which masks the final required dictionary format which was causing the problem.

If there is a way for this to be somehow handled in a more direct method as specified in the original question I would love to know. Thanks for those who commented.

**Solution**

```
import itertools as it

def standKeys():
    # Standard input parameters for dymola.simulateExtendedModel
    keys = ['n1',
            'n2',
            'varString',
            'varName',
            'varVal']
    return keys


def initSettings():
    # Initialize the settings parameters
    simSettings = {}
    for key in standKeys():
            simSettings[key]=None

    return simSettings

def genExperimentsRaw(simSettings):
    # Remove None and generate all experiment permutations
    simSettingsfiltered = {k:v for k,v in simSettings.items() if v is not None}
    keys, values = zip(*simSettingsfiltered.items())
    experimentsRaw = [dict(zip(keys, v)) for v in it.product(*values)]

    return experimentsRaw

def genExperiments(experimentsRaw):
    # Filter experiments to generate key/value pairs for 'varName' and 'varVal'
    allKeys = standKeys()
    experiments = []
    for i, value in enumerate(experimentsRaw):
        initialNames = []
        initialValues = []
        for key, val in value.items(): 
            if key not in allKeys:
                initialNames.append(key)
                initialValues.append(val)
                value.pop(key)
        value['varName']=initialNames
        value['varVal']=initialValues

        experiments.append(initSettings())
        experiments[i].update(value)

    return experiments

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d={}
    d['n1']=[1,100]
    d['n2']=None
    d['varString']=['ExampleText']
    # Original
    # d['varName']=['varA','varB'] # Remove this
    # d['varVal']=[[10],[1,0]]

    # Separate out and treat like other dictionary keys
    d['varA']=[10]
    d['varB']=[1,0]

# Generate all experiment permutations
experimentsRaw = genExperimentsRaw(d)

# Filter experiments to generate key/value pairs for 'varName' and 'varVal'
experiments = genExperiments(experimentsRaw)
```

**Result**

```
[{'n1': 1,
  'n2': None,
  'varName': ['varA', 'varB'],
  'varString': 'ExampleText',
  'varVal': [10, 1]},
 {'n1': 1,
  'n2': None,
  'varName': ['varA', 'varB'],
  'varString': 'ExampleText',
  'varVal': [10, 0]},
 {'n1': 100,
  'n2': None,
  'varName': ['varA', 'varB'],
  'varString': 'ExampleText',
  'varVal': [10, 1]},
 {'n1': 100,
  'n2': None,
  'varName': ['varA', 'varB'],
  'varString': 'ExampleText',
  'varVal': [10, 0]}]
```